# R function to limit characters of list element name?

Tags: r, excel, export

I have a list of elements. I want to export this list as an excel file with each element exporting as an individual sheet within the same excel file. Excel has a 31 character limit for sheet names. Thus the below export will not work.

Is there a way to limit the characters of a list using a function? For example, cut off all element names at 30 characters?

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

test1 <- list(employee, salary, startdate)

names(test1)[1] <- "employee of the month 2021 to 2022"
names(test1)[2] <- "salary of the best employees of test company"
names(test1)[3] <- "startdate"

write.xlsx(test1, file = "testlist.xlsx")
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this approach you can save space by defining a stopwords list, so there is more space for meaningful sheetnames. The example includes the change of your names in your test1 list. Either keep the words in tact, or cut of words "halfway".

```
library(stringi)

# remove words without much meaning, add what you like
stopwords <- c("of", "the", "to")

names(test1) <- unlist(lapply(names(test1), function (x){
  x <- stri_extract_all_words(x)[[1]]
  x <- paste(x[!x %in% stopwords], collapse = " ")
  # strwrap(x, width = 30)[1] # keep words in tact
  substr(x, start = 1, stop = 30)
}))

names(test1)

# strwrap uncommented
# [1] "employee month 2021 2022"   "salary best employees test" "startdate"

# substr uncommented
# [1] "employee month 2021 2022"        "salary best employees test com" "startdate" 

# compare that to the outcome without removing stopwords
# [1] "employee of the month 2021 to " "salary of the best employees o" "startdate"
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run the script, I get this error: "Error in stri_extract_all_words(x) : could not find function "stri_extract_all_words"". Is there something I am missing?

Comment: it is part of `library(stringr)`

Comment: The package was already loaded, odd. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: my apology, I used `stringi` but wrongly loaded `stringr` instead in the posted answer. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Function `substr` will work.

```
> substr("salary of the best employees of test company", start = 1, stop = 30)
[1] "salary of the best employees o"
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to create a function with this to apply to all the elements in a list? My working data has many more elements

Comment: The `substr` function is vectorized, so just pass a vector of element (i.e. `names(test1)`) you wish to have truncated.